# Choosing rheostat ratings

Tags: plug, ratings, rheostat

I want to control a heated pad with a rheostat. My heated pad has a power rating of 30W and supply voltage of 12V DC. How do I calculate the ratings required for my rheostat and plug adapter? I have very little experience with electronics so a simple explanation would be best.

Answer (score 1):

From \$ P = VI \$ we can calculate that the current required is \$ I = \frac P V = \frac {30}{12} = 2.5\ \text A\$.

From Ohm's law, \$ V = IR \$ we can calculate that \$ R = \frac V I = \frac {12}{2.5} = 5 \ \Omega \$ approximately.

If you add a 5 Ω, 30 W rheostat in series with your load you will be able to adjust the power down from 30 W. We can rewrite the power law as \$ P = \frac {V^2} R = \frac {12} {5 + 5} = \frac {144}{10} = 14.4 \text W \$ so you would dissipate 7.2 W in your pad and 7.2 W in the rheostat.

You'd be looking for something like a 10 W, 5 Ω rheostat.

Note that a much more efficient way would be to use pulse-width modulation (PWM) control which switches the heater on and off quickly enough that the temperature remains quite constant but avoids the losses associated with additional resistance.